# How to count entities properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method which has an attribute "user" and I'm trying to check if he's already in a team of the given "course"

```
        private static bool UserIsInTeamOfCourse(Course course, User user)
        {
            var count = course.Teams.Count(x => x.Users.Contains(user));
            if (count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

But it doesn't work. I made a custom Equals method in my User model, but it still don't work.
[EDIT] It always counts zero entries, but there have to be at least one entry.

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return UserId == ((User)obj).UserId;

    }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Throws an error? Always returns zero? Always returns all the values?

Comment: It always returns a zero although there's this user in one of the teams.

Comment: Why use Count when you don't want to count the elements? Use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

Comment: Is there something in the `course.Teams` collection at all? If you don't use lazy loading this won't issue any query to the DB. It's simply a query in memory (LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entities). If `course.Teams` is empty your result will be 0. Are you using EF 4.0 or EF 4.1?

Comment: Yes I monitored the variable and the entries were there, also the users were there. I use EF4.1.

Comment: OK, then the first line in my answer below or @cinek's answer should really work. It's simply LINQ in memory then and `Any` is easier than `Contains` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isUserInAnyTeam = course.Teams.Any(t => t.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id));
```

This is LINQ to Objects because you are querying on the `Teams` collection in memory. So it assumes that the `Teams` collection is already loaded or will be lazily loaded. If it's not loaded and you don't use lazy loading you can create a database query on the collection:

In EF 4.1 with DbContext:

```
bool isUserInAnyTeam = dbContext.Entry(course).Collection(c => c.Teams).Query()
                                .Any(t => t.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id));
```

Or in EF 4.0:

```
bool isUserInAnyTeam = course.Teams.CreateSourceQuery()    
                             .Any(t => t.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id));
```

`Teams` must be of type `EntityCollection<Team>` in the last case.

Another way is to query from scratch:

```
bool isUserInAnyTeamOfCourse = context.Courses.Any(
  c => c.Id == course.Id && c.Teams.Any(t => t.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a many to many relationship betweens teams and users and a user will not be part twice of the same team.

```
var count = (from c in context.Teams
            from u in c.Users
            where u.Id == 1
            select c.Id).Count();
```

Entity framework can not translate your c# code in which you've overriden equals to a sql function.

Comment: Are you sure about that?
Because I use the `UserIsInTeamOfCourse` twice. One time from a controller to restrict access to an action and one time from a view to show the "Join" button or to hide it.
If I call the method from the controller it calls the `Equals` method of the `User` class. If the method is called by the view it doesn't access the `Equals` method.

Comment: That's the difference between LINQ to Entities (aka Entity Framework) and LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing custom objects compare userID (which is probably int or other simple type)

```
    private static bool UserIsInTeamOfCourse(Course course, User user)
    {
        return course.Teams.Where(team => team.Users.Any(u => u.userID == user.userID)).Count() > 0;
    }
```